# Store procedure doesnt return a variable in MVC4 using Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

Hi  i have a Stored Procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAlbum @name nvarchar(30), @Generename nvarchar(30)   
AS  
SELECT *  
FROM CoroporateApps.dbo.Album  
WHERE Artist = @name AND Genre = @Generename
```

i have a controller like this

```
public ActionResult ReturnAlbumList(FormCollection form)
        {
            CoroporateAppsEntities storeDB = new CoroporateAppsEntities();
             string strArtist= Request.Form["Album"].ToString();
           string strGenre = Request.Form["GenreList"].ToString();
            var AlbumType = storeDB.getAlbum(strArtist, strGenre);
                return View(AlbumType);
        }
```

and i have a view like this 
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AlbumList";


    <div>
     @if (Model.Count() > 0)
     {
          <table>

     @foreach (var item in Model)
      {

      <tr>
      <td>@item.AlbumId</td>
      <td>@item.GenreId</td>
      <td>@item.ArtistId</td>
      <td>@item.Title</td>
      <td>@item.Price</td>
      <td>@item.AlbumUrl</td>
      <td>@item.Genre</td>
      <td>@item.Artist</td>

      </tr>  

     }
      </table>
      }
    </div>
```

But when i am running my application i am unable to get the value in Variable AlbumType can anyone please tell me how to get the value from store procedure and store it in variable

Answer (score 0):

try `storeDB.getAlbum(strArtist, strGenre).Tolist();`